# Gmail API get messages 'cannot resolve method execute()'

Tags: java, api, intellij-idea, gmail

I am trying to run the example java code for Users.messages:list (below). However, my IDE (IntelliJ) errors on the 'execute()' method:

> 'cannot resolve method execute()'

I have the necessary dependency, **google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev43-1.2.2.0.jar**. Is there another dependency that I am missing?

```
 /**
   * List all Messages of the user's mailbox matching the query.
   *
   * @param service Authorized Gmail API instance.
   * @param userId User's email address. The special value "me"
   * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
   * @param query String used to filter the Messages listed.
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static List<Message> listMessagesMatchingQuery(Gmail service, String userId,String query) throws IOException {
    ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list(userId).setQ(query).execute();
```

Error: **cannot resolve method execute() compile**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Try adding this dependency in gradle file, it solved my issue.

**compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev48-1.22.0'**